# Lodash group by a complex object

Tags: lodash

I have this data

```
 var data = [
        {id:23, family:{familyId:1,name:'AAA',code:'A'},
        {id:24, family:{familyId:1,name:'AAA',code:'A'},
        {id:25, family:{familyId:2,name:'BBB',code:'B'},
        {id:26, family:{familyId:2,name:'BBB',code:'B'}
 ];
```

And I want to **group by the whole object family**, but this doesn't work:

```
_(data).groupBy(x => x.family).value();

// Returns  {[object Object]: Array(4)}
```

Of course this works:

```
_(data).groupBy(x => x.family.code).value();

 // Returns: {A: Array(2), B: Array(2)}
```

But then my key is just a value and not the entire object

At the end I'd like to have this:

```
 var groupedData = [
        {
            family:{familyId:1,name:'AAA',code:'A'},
            data:[
                {id:23, family:{familyId:1,name:'AAA',code:'A'},
                {id:24, family:{familyId:1,name:'AAA',code:'A'}
            ]
        },
        {
            family:{familyId:2,name:'BBB',code:'B'},
            data:[
                {id:25, family:{familyId:2,name:'BBB',code:'B'},
                {id:26, family:{familyId:2,name:'BBB',code:'B'}
            ]
        },
 ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **lodash** you can do something like this:

```js
var data = [{ id: 23, family: { familyId: 1, name: 'AAA', code: 'A' } }, { id: 24, family: { familyId: 1, name: 'AAA', code: 'A' } }, { id: 25, family: { familyId: 2, name: 'BBB', code: 'B' } }, { id: 26, family: { familyId: 2, name: 'BBB', code: 'B' } } ];

const result = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy('family.familyId')
  .mapValues(x => ({ family: _.head(x).family, data: x }))
  .values()
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

It is a `groupBy` to group on the `familyId` followed by `values` and `reduce` to get to the object you want.

With **ES6** you can do similar:

```js
var data = [{ id: 23, family: { familyId: 1, name: 'AAA', code: 'A' } }, { id: 24, family: { familyId: 1, name: 'AAA', code: 'A' } }, { id: 25, family: { familyId: 2, name: 'BBB', code: 'B' } }, { id: 26, family: { familyId: 2, name: 'BBB', code: 'B' } } ];

const grp = (d,i) =>
   d.reduce((r,c) => (r[c.family[i]] = [...r[c.family[i]] || [], c], r), {})
const r = Object.values(grp(data,'familyId')).map(x=>({family: x[0], data: x}))

console.log(r)
```

Same idea with a custom `groupBy` tailored for this exmaple and followed by `Object.values` and then mapping the values to the desired output.

Comment: shouldnt be `_.head(x).family`?